# Attachments not working with WP8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Are WP8 attachments supported with version 0.8.2 of cordova email composer (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer)?

I thought they are because of:

- There is a mention "[enhancement:] Support attachments on Windows Phone 8.1" in the release notes...
- There is a mention "The plugin may crash on WP8.1/Windows if an attachmant does not exist." in the documentation

However, I have some doubts since:

- I have not succeed to get the attachments working
- There is a mention "Attachments and HTML+CSS formatted body are not supported through the native API for Windows Phone 8.0 and Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight" in the documentation

So, could someone either explicit tell if it is possible to attach a file with WP8 and the plugin or not?

This is how I got it working with Android and iOS. WP just opens the email but without the attachment.

```
var attachment = 'base64:' + pdfName + '//,' + arrayBufferToBase64(document);

cordova.plugins.email.open({
    to:      to,
    subject: subject,
    body:    body,
    attachments: [attachment],
    isHtml: false
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, with this plugin, it is not possible.
If you look at the code, in [this file](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/blob/master/src/wp8/EmailComposer.cs%20%22this%20file') 
, the method `SetAttachments` is not implemented.